# How to override getattr or getattribute in python to call gettattr or getattribute inside itself as in lazy recursive directory listing

Tags: python, setattr

For example something like this:

```py
class DotTabLoader():
    def __init__(self, basedir, loaderfun):
        self._basedir = pathlib.PosixPath(basedir)
        self._loaderfun = loaderfun
        self._list = list(self._basedir.glob('*/'))
        self._names = [x.name.split('=')[1] for x in self._list]
        self._names_dict = dict(zip(self._names, range(self._names)))
    def __dir__(self):
        return self._names
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        # how to access self._list etc here?
        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

You get errors with infinite recursion.

**UPDATE:**

Correct way is this:

```py
class DotTabLoader():
    def __init__(self, basedir, loaderfun):
        self._basedir = pathlib.PosixPath(basedir)
        self._loaderfun = loaderfun
        self._list = list(self._basedir.glob('*/'))
        self._names = [x.name.split('=')[1] for x in self._list]
        self._names_dict = dict(zip(self._names, range(len(self._names))))
    def __dir__(self):
        return self._names + super().__dir__()
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            ind = self._names_dict[name]
            basedir = self._list[ind]
            return DotTabLoader(basedir, self._loaderfun)
        except KeyError as e:
            return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method is to implement `__getattr__`, which is only called if a normal lookup fails.  That means that you can access normal attributes inside your `__getattr__` implementation without having to do anything special, and it won't be called recursively because the base class lookup succeeds.

```
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self._list[0]  # works fine!
```

`__getattribute__` is more of a special case because it's called unconditionally rather than as a fallback to the normal lookup.  Per the docs ([https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**getattribute**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__))
if you want to access an attribute inside `__getattribute__` without calling your own overridden `__getattribute__` implementation you need to call the `object` implementation:

```
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return object.__getattribute__(self, '_list')[0]
```

Comment: Yep, there is a lot of search noise on this from the past. I've even done this before but couldn't find it right away.